# How does this Verilog Code work? It has two separate but same negedge conditions within the same always block statement

Tags: verilog

I am wondering this code works perfectly. I want to understand how the two negedge states work within the always block.

````
#5 clk = ~clk;

always
begin
@(negedge clk) din = 1;
@(negedge clk) din = 0;
end ```
````

Comment: I have seen the simulation. The _din_ value changes one after the other. But I thought since these statements are within the same _always block_ the last _negedge__ will always override the value assigned to _din_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simulation will do the following:

1. start the always block execution
2. wait for negedge of clk
3. assign 1 to din
4. wait for negedge of clk (the next one)
5. assign 0 to din
6. re-start execution of the always block, go to step 1.

So, value of din will alternate between negedges of clk.

Answer (score 0):

The `@(expression)` is a construct that waits for a change in the state of the expressio. `posedge` qualifies the change from 0 to something else.

A change is an event that is like a trigger, or a quantum in time. Your code has to be waiting for the expression to change when the change happens. So the second `@(posedge clk)` waits for the *next* posedge of clk.

Consider this code

```
always @(postage clk)
     begin 
        #11 din = in;
     end
```

This always block executes at every other posedge because the posedge event happens while the procedure is waiting for #11 time units to pass.